# What is a "full beam master suite"?

Tags: english-to-german

I am currently reading a small article about a luxury yacht and there was the term "full beam master suite" used to describe one of the staterooms... Does anyone have an idea or even a German translation for that term? Trying to translate it myself didn't take me much further.
Kind regards

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks for the meaning of an English word and thus requires expertise of the English, not the German language.

Answer (score 4):

"Full beam" bedeutet "über die volle Breite des Schiffs". Der "Master" ist der "Schiffsführer", aber die "master suite" wird auch (wenn es faktisch passt) gerne als die "Eignerkabine" bezeichnet (eben die größte Kabine an Bord, die für den Eigner reserviert ist, wenn er sie braucht).

Wenn man sich einige [Übersetzungsbeispiele](http://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/search?source=auto&query=full+beam+suite) anschaut, findet man, dass bei den vernünftigen Übersetzungen "full beam" fast immer umschrieben wird, statt als eigenständiger Begriff übersetzt zu werden.